# Resizing NSMutableArray in Objective-C for passing into coreML model

Tags: objective-c, resize, nsmutablearray, nsarray, coreml

I am trying to load a 2d image stored as an NSMutableArray (of semi-random sizing), resize the array to 512x512, and then feed into a coreML model as an Image (Grayscale 512x512)for prediction. Is there an efficient way to do this? Convert the NsMutableArray to UIImage/NSImage/CVPixelBuffer first and then resize? Can any of these types satisfy the "Image (Grayscale 512x512)" input?

I've tried converting to NSImage and resizing then feeding the resulting image directly into the model:

```
NSSize newSize;
newSize.height = 512;
newSize.width = 512;

const NSImage* segImage = [Viewer1.imageView nsimage:YES];
[segImage setScalesWhenResized:YES];

int widthNSI = [segImage size].width;
int heightNSI = [segImage size].height;
NSLog(@"NSImage original width: %i", widthNSI);
NSLog(@"NSImage original height: %i", heightNSI);

NSImage *resized = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize: newSize];
[resized lockFocus];
[segImage setSize: newSize];
[[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] setImageInterpolation: NSImageInterpolationHigh];
[segImage drawAtPoint:NSZeroPoint fromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height) operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:1.0];
[resized unlockFocus];

int widthRES = [resized size].width;
int heightRES = [resized size].height;
NSLog(@"NSImage adjusted width: %i", widthRES);
NSLog(@"NSImage adjusted height: %i", heightRES);


coremodel_segment *model = nil;
model = [[coremodel_segment alloc] init];
```

This seems to be spitting out the resized image (I haven't been able to visualize but the dimensions at least are okay based on the log). When I try to make a prediction however I get:

```
-[MLNeuralNetworkEngine predictionFromInput:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7faf43c9a1c0
```

So I'm guessing either 1. the NSImage format isn't compatible (does it need to be CVPixelFormat?), 2. I'm doing something wrong with the resizing, or 3. I'm calling the predict function incorrectly.

I've also tried converting the NSImage to CVPixel with:

```
CVPixelBufferRef buffer = NULL;
size_t width = [resized size].width;
size_t height = [resized size].height;
size_t bitsPerComponent = 8; // *not* CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(image);
CGColorSpaceRef cs = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericRGB);
CGBitmapInfo bi = kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst; // *not* CGImageGetBitmapInfo(image);
NSDictionary *d = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey, [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey, nil];
CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, width, height, k32ARGBPixelFormat, (CFDictionaryRef)d, &buffer);
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(buffer, 0);
void *rasterData = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(buffer);
size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(buffer);
CGContextRef ctxt = CGBitmapContextCreate(rasterData, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, cs, bi);
if(ctxt == NULL){
    NSLog(@"could not create context");
    return NULL;
}
NSGraphicsContext *nsctxt = [NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithGraphicsPort:ctxt flipped:NO];
[NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
[NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext:nsctxt];
[resized compositeToPoint:NSMakePoint(0.0, 0.0) operation:NSCompositeCopy];
[NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(buffer, 0);
CFRelease(ctxt);

coremodel_segmentOutput *prediction = [model predictionFromData:buffer error:nil];
```

but I receive the same error.

I realize in the CVPixelBufferConversionCode I list the color space as RBG, not sure if this would cause any issues.. (GenericGray caused different issues)

```
CGColorSpaceRef cs = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericRGB);
```

Not sure if this helps, but here is the models header://

```
// coremodel_segment.h
//
// This file was automatically generated and should not be edited.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreML/CoreML.h>
#include <stdint.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN


/// Model Prediction Input Type
API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.13), ios(11.0), watchos(4.0), tvos(11.0)) __attribute__((visibility("hidden")))
@interface coremodel_segmentInput : NSObject<MLFeatureProvider>

/// data as grayscale (kCVPixelFormatType_OneComponent8) image buffer, 512 pixels wide by 512 pixels high
@property (readwrite, nonatomic) CVPixelBufferRef data;
- (instancetype)init NS_UNAVAILABLE;
- (instancetype)initWithData:(CVPixelBufferRef)data;
@end


/// Model Prediction Output Type
API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.13), ios(11.0), watchos(4.0), tvos(11.0)) __attribute__((visibility("hidden")))
@interface coremodel_segmentOutput : NSObject<MLFeatureProvider>

/// image as 1 x 512 x 512 3-dimensional array of doubles
@property (readwrite, nonatomic, strong) MLMultiArray * image;
- (instancetype)init NS_UNAVAILABLE;
- (instancetype)initWithImage:(MLMultiArray *)image;
@end


/// Class for model loading and prediction
API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.13), ios(11.0), watchos(4.0), tvos(11.0)) __attribute__((visibility("hidden")))
@interface coremodel_segment : NSObject
@property (readonly, nonatomic, nullable) MLModel * model;
- (nullable instancetype)init;
- (nullable instancetype)initWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url error:(NSError * _Nullable * _Nullable)error;
- (nullable instancetype)initWithConfiguration:(MLModelConfiguration *)configuration error:(NSError * _Nullable * _Nullable)error API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.14), ios(12.0), watchos(5.0), tvos(12.0)) __attribute__((visibility("hidden")));
- (nullable instancetype)initWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url configuration:(MLModelConfiguration *)configuration error:(NSError * _Nullable * _Nullable)error API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.14), ios(12.0), watchos(5.0), tvos(12.0)) __attribute__((visibility("hidden")));

/**
    Make a prediction using the standard interface
    @param input an instance of coremodel_segmentInput to predict from
    @param error If an error occurs, upon return contains an NSError object that describes the problem. If you are not interested in possible errors, pass in NULL.
    @return the prediction as coremodel_segmentOutput
*/
- (nullable coremodel_segmentOutput *)predictionFromFeatures:(coremodel_segmentInput *)input error:(NSError * _Nullable * _Nullable)error;

/**
    Make a prediction using the standard interface
    @param input an instance of coremodel_segmentInput to predict from
    @param options prediction options
    @param error If an error occurs, upon return contains an NSError object that describes the problem. If you are not interested in possible errors, pass in NULL.
    @return the prediction as coremodel_segmentOutput
*/
- (nullable coremodel_segmentOutput *)predictionFromFeatures:(coremodel_segmentInput *)input options:(MLPredictionOptions *)options error:(NSError * _Nullable * _Nullable)error;

/**
    Make a prediction using the convenience interface
    @param data as grayscale (kCVPixelFormatType_OneComponent8) image buffer, 512 pixels wide by 512 pixels high:
    @param error If an error occurs, upon return contains an NSError object that describes the problem. If you are not interested in possible errors, pass in NULL.
    @return the prediction as coremodel_segmentOutput
*/
- (nullable coremodel_segmentOutput *)predictionFromData:(CVPixelBufferRef)data error:(NSError * _Nullable * _Nullable)error;

/**
    Batch prediction
    @param inputArray array of coremodel_segmentInput instances to obtain predictions from
    @param options prediction options
    @param error If an error occurs, upon return contains an NSError object that describes the problem. If you are not interested in possible errors, pass in NULL.
    @return the predictions as NSArray<coremodel_segmentOutput *>
*/
- (nullable NSArray<coremodel_segmentOutput *> *)predictionsFromInputs:(NSArray<coremodel_segmentInput*> *)inputArray options:(MLPredictionOptions *)options error:(NSError * _Nullable * _Nullable)error API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.14), ios(12.0), watchos(5.0), tvos(12.0)) __attribute__((visibility("hidden")));
@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

The model was saved with:
segment_model =

```
coremltools.converters.keras.convert('/Users/.../Downloads/model_segment.h5', input_names='data', image_input_names='data', output_names='image');
segment_model.save('/Users/.../Downloads/coremodel_segment.mlmodel');
```

where I added input names so the input form would be an image instead of MultiArray. I tried changing the prediction line to "data" instead of "input":
    coremodel_segmentOutput *prediction = [model predictionFromData:buffer error:nil];
and now get this in my console:

```
Error Domain=com.apple.CoreML Code=1 UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=<private>, NSUnderlyingError=0x600003982340 {Error Domain=com.apple.CoreML Code=1 UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=<private>}}}
Failure verifying inputs.
```

Comment: Have you tried any approach? could you post your code here? like method signatures, workflow and so on.

Comment: It needs to be a CVPixelBufferRef object. However, what is the type of `model`, is it an `MLModel`? If yes, then note that this class does not have a `predictionFromInput` method, which is the error message you're getting.

Comment: It should be Type: Neural Network, I realize I declared 'model' in the .h file as `MLModel *model;` without that I still get the error `-[coremodel_segment predictionFromInput:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000196a150`

Comment: `coremodel_segment` does not have a method that is named `predictionFromInput`, which is why you get an "unrecognized selector error". The "Failure verifying inputs" error is because your image is not a CVPixelBuffer object, has the wrong pixel format, or has the wrong dimensions.